# How to use namespace or type alias/abbreviation?

Tags: f#

What's the equivalent F# declaration to this C# declaration:

using NR = ICSharpCode.NRefactory;

Answer (score 49):

abbreviations in F# can be applied to modules:

```
module ES = Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.ExprShape
```

and [types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233246.aspx)

```
type Thread = System.Threading.Thread
```

unfortunatly just namespaces cannot be abbreviated

Comment: It should be noted that the first syntax above is called a ["Local module declaration"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/modules) and the RH-side must also be module. As the name suggests, the abbreviation really works as an alias and is not scoped outside the current file. The type abbreviation is scoped depending on your modifiers: `type private`, or `type public` etc.

Comment: As a further aside: the module alias inherits whatever tooltip comment its original has, the type abbreviation will not, and you should give it its own info comment with `///`.

Answer (score 7):

Equivalent F# declaration would be:

```
type NR = ICSharpCode.NRefactory
```

In F# it's called a *type abreviation*:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233246.aspx

But `ICSharpCode.NRefactory` has to be here a type, as desco said just namespaces cannot be abbreviated.