# Namespace aliasing in F#?

Tags: f#, namespaces, alias

I have a name clashing problem while opening some .Net assemblies in my F# code using

```
open System.IO
```

The only option I found and use now is to provide the full names of types for conflicting types, but this is a little bit boring.

Is there any possibility to define an alias for .Net namespace in F# to prevent name clashing?

Comment: There has been a request for "namespace aliasing", but it has been declined by Don Syme. Unfortunately, his rationale fell victim to linkrot, so [asked about this on the F# forum](https://forums.fsharp.org/t/why-was-the-namespace-aliasing-feature-request-declined/3586).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

F# does not support aliasing of namespaces - only modules and types. So, to resolve the conflicts between .NET assemblies, you will, unfortunatelly, need to define aliases for all the types you're using.

This may be slightly easier thanks to the fact that F# type aliases are viewed as normal type declarations (by the F# compiler, not by the runtime). This means that, unlike with C# `using` keyword, you can define them in a spearate file:

```
// Aliases.fs
namespace SysIO

// Open the 'System' namespace to get a bit shorter syntax
// ('type File = File' is interpreted as discriminated union)
open System

type File = IO.File
type Directory = IO.Directory
```

In the rest of your application, you can now use `SysIO.File`. You still have to write the aliases, but at least you don't have to do that in every file...

Comment: This is a nice solution, I just need a handful of types.

Comment: "only modules and types": it is only types, modules cannot be aliased. would be happily wrong.

Comment: happily wrong i am . modules can be aliased like so: module ACMEStore = ACME.DB.Store  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918744/how-to-use-namespace-or-type-alias-abbreviation)