# Is is possible to alias a module with another name in F#

Tags: f#

let's say I have this:

```
module A =
    let a () =
        printfn "%A" DateTime.UtcNow
```

is there a way to do something like

```
type B = A
B.a()
```

or, any other mechanism that would allow to set up an alias?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Namespace aliasing in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379043/namespace-aliasing-in-f)

Comment: @KoenigLear actually one link in the last answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918744/how-to-use-namespace-or-type-alias-abbreviation answers the questions; so to alias a module, you have to do module a = b... makes sense :)  thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can alias modules in F#, but the syntax is `module <NewName> = <OldName>`:

```
module A =
    let a () =
        printfn "%A" DateTime.UtcNow

module B = A
B.a()
```